# .NetCore 2.2: How to get a private key of a certificate?

Tags: .net-core, x509certificate, private-key

for the implementation of an API I use, I need to provide a certificate, which consists of 2 byte arrays one for the public key and the other one for private key.

My initial idea was to do this with X509Certificate object of .Net. But I am struggling to get the private key bytes.

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("testCert.pfx", password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
byte[] myPublicKey = certificate.GetRawCertData();
byte[] privateKey = ???
```

I've tried to export the key, but I can't export the private key standalone.
And:

```
certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
```

is not available on a Ubuntu System :-(

Do you have any ideas, how to get the private bytes from certificates?
May be X509Certificate2 is not the best solution for this...

Comment: It would be much easier to use 3.0, where there are new key export methods, like `AsymmetricAlgorithm.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey`.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I wil check this, but I would be really happy to find a solution for 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Use an approrpiate method of these [X509Certificate2 extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#extension-methods):

- `GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2)` -- for RSA keys
- `GetDSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2)` -- for DSA keys
- `GetECDsaPrivateKey(X509Certificate2)` -- for EC keys

Extension method you need to use depends on asymmtric key algorithm.

Comment: I can get such a RSA key - but how to proceed with this object?
The method ToXmlString(true) is not supported on my platform. And ExportParameters doesn't really help me

Comment: Check this thread on GitHub with a sample workaround: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23686